# How to get relative links work in wamp or set wamp/www/mysite to act as the root?

Tags: php, hyperlink, wamp

My website lives in wamp/www/mysite. There is an index.php and all the other files live in wamp/www/mysite/foo. Inside the foo dir there are also two include-files, header.php and footer.php. Relative links in that two files do not work properly. They act like wamp/www is the root dir.

I have tried both ways: `/foo/somepage.php` and `foo/somepage.php`

On a live server everything works perfect.
How can I fix that?

OS: Windows 7

Comment: Show the links you are using.

Comment: I have done some edits

Comment: Try using just `somepage.php` if the files are all in the `foo` folder. The leading `backslash` means go back to the server root (which is `c:\wamp\www` and the `foo\somepage.php` means look in a subfolder of `here` for a foo folder.

Comment: I include `header.php` and `footer.php` in `index.php` that is outside `foo`, so it will not work for it. It is clearly a wamp's problem, on a live servers works just fine.

Comment: Then use the format `foo\header.php` when in `index.php`

Comment: Are you sure that the location is:  www/wamp/mysite and not  wamp/www/mysite?
If it is what you say it is then wamp/www would not be the root dir!

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. Edited!

Comment: if you run the script in a directory called A and you include a script that is found in directory B, then the relative path will be resolved relative to directory A

Comment: @RiggsFolly I use one `header.php` for both index.php and files in `foo` so it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

On WAMP relative link like `/foo/somepage.php` point to `wamp/www/foo/somepage.php`, not `wamp/www/mysite/foo/somepage.php`

Your site may work on WAMP using relative links, but you need to install it on root `wamp/www` or configure virtual hosts

[See how to setup virtual hosts on WAMP](http://www.codeforest.net/multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp)

Comment: Thanks but I do not use WAMP and Windows anymore, so I am not able to check if it works.

Comment: this is wrong for me... i put my Zend/application.php in wamp/www/ and this not work to.

Answer (score 0):

When in scripts that live in `wamp/www/mysite` use :

```
include( 'foo/header.php' );
```

When in scripts that live in `wamp/www/mysite\foo` use :

```
include( 'header.php' );
```

Comment: That's my current. It's not about wrong typed paths or includes, it is about wamp understanding as root `wamp/www` and not `wamp/www/mysite`